# How to run a command in Visual Studio Code with launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to execute an `ssh` command when debugging a project with `.vscode/launch.json`?

For example: `ssh -i xxxxx`.

Or is it possible to create a command that you can run from the <kbd>F1</kbd> command palette pop-up? Something like `RunCustomCommandxx`.

Comment: there is also https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabrielgrinberg.auto-run-command

Answer (score 156):

You can define a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) in your `tasks.json` file and specify that as the `preLaunchTask` in your `launch.json` and the task will be executed before debugging begins.

Example:

**In tasks.json**:

For version 0.1.0:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "taskName": "echotest",
        "command": "echo", // Could be any other shell command
        "args": ["test"],
        "isShellCommand": true
    }]
}
```

For version 2.0.0 (newer and recommended):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "echotest",
        "command": "echo", // Could be any other shell command
        "args": ["test"],
        "type": "shell"
    }]
}
```

**In launch.json:**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            // ...
            "preLaunchTask": "echotest", // The name of the task defined above
            // ...
        }
    ]   
}
```

Tasks documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Launch configuration: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: Hi Saravana, thanks for the response, Im getting a error: Failed to launch external program ssh -i ~/.ssh/some_key -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 forge@xxx.203.107.80 .
spawn ssh -i ~/.ssh/some_key -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 forge@xxx.203.100.80 ENOENT

Comment: Make sure ssh is in your path. Or give the absolute path in your command.

Comment: @user3466947, isn't `Address already in use` saying you enough? Connect to the machine with ssh and try `netstat -lnpt` to see if the process is `already using the address`.

Comment: Which type of launch configuration do you use? The ones I have (e.g., python) require a "program" path...I guess I could just set it to a dummy python file. But, I don't really even want to engage the debugger, just run my task.

Comment: I tried this in GNU\Linux to set an environment variable. The task fired off as expected, but I don't think the environment variable is getting passed through to launch.json. Did I do something wrong or is what I'm trying to do impossible?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317136/how-can-i-get-a-task-to-set-a-variable-that-can-be-used-in-a-configuration

Comment: I believe this is out-of-date, now you can use `type: node-terminal` as described below.

Answer (score 49):

The format changed. Visual Studio Code can create the `tasks.json` file for you. Inside your `launch.json` file and inside any configurations object, just define `preLaunchTask` to force auto-creation of the `tasks.json` template file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "launch program",
        "skipFiles": [ "<node_internals>/**"],
        "preLaunchTask": "myShellCommand",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js"
      }
  ]
}
```

If you do not have file `tasks.json` configured:

- launch the debugger. Visual Studio Code will inform you: *"could not find the task
  myShellCommand"*
- select *Configure Task* → *Create tasks.json file
  from template* → *Others*

Your `tasks.json` template file will then be created for you. Add your command to `command` and the name you put in `preLaunchTask` to `label`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "myShellCommand",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo goodfood"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: in `launch.json` of .vscode: can I remove the `program` key because I just want to run the prelaunchtask as described?

Answer (score 16):

For me, I just needed an environment variable, which is different. You don't want a task for this because (at least for me) it doesn't work when the launcher is run.

Thanks to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1683), I got it working like this, inside my launcher (launch.json) entry:

```
"environment": [{
    "name": "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME",
    "value": "${workspaceFolder}/lib" //Set to whatever value you want.
}],
```

Answer (score 11):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch app",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Build an APK Release",
            "command": "flutter build apk --release",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node-terminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Install an APK on a device",
            "command": "flutter install",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node-terminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's possible.
Just use:

```
"type": "node-terminal"
```

(don't worry it says '**node**-terminal', it should work out-of-the-box in VS Code)

and specify your command in "command" property:

```
"command": "ssh -i xxxx"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the most elegant way out of all the other solutions IMO

Answer (score 4):

My version of the configuration allows to just run a defined task and carried on (in my case, the task is to run the currently open [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) file):

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch groovy",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "preLaunchTask": "groovy",
        "program": "cmd.exe",
        "args": ["/c"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
]
```

And the task:

```json
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "groovy",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "groovy ${file}"
    }
]
```

Comment: I did this, and my tasks command is ran, however it does not carry on to launch the python file debugging. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

To create a launch configuration, use the PowerShell Visual Studio extension and place your commands in the script.

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Build and run",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": " ${workspaceFolder}\\launch.ps1",
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.ps1

```
Start-Process -FilePath ssh -ArgumentList "-i","xxxxx" -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

for flutter developers who is searching how to run flutter build commands.
in tasks.json add

```json
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "flutter",
            "command": "flutter",
            "args": [
                "pub",
                "run",
                "build_runner",
                "build",
                "--delete-conflicting-outputs"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$dart-build_runner"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "flutter: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs"
        },
]
```

then from vscode you can try "run task" it will show you `flutter: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

this way you don't need to memorize and type to terminal source code generation/build commands