# How to use GCC for compilation and debug on VSCode

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

I have found out a few different ways to debug C with the GCC compiler, however I want to have debugging on by default. Is there any way I can do this with a setting in my `launch.json` in VSCode?

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your CFLAGS: `-gdwarf-4 -g3`

To do that, run this command:

```
export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -gdwarf-4 -g3"
```

See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/FAQs.md#how-to-enable-debug-symbols) link for more information and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/vs-code-run-command-at-launch-json) link for running commands in `launch.json`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
Sadly it's says "Property CFLAGS is not allowed." 
may you please add a full example?

Comment: See updated answer. I'm not exactly sure if and how you can do this. To be honest, I don't usually use proprietary editors like VSCode. I use open-source alternatives (the non-Microsoft version, `code-oss`).