# VS Code launch.json externalTerminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Ok, so long story short, I can run simple java files on vscode with output on the internal consol. My question is, how can I change the launch.json configuration so I can get the output of the .java file on a new terminal window? I have tried changing the launch.json and adding "console" : "externalTerminal" but always get "failed to launch debuggee in terminal" error

Comment: Exact error ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/vs-code-run-command-at-launch-json

Answer (score 0):

I simply did `rm ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` and it worked for me.