# Set env var for Node JS when launching through VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have Node JS Azure function that when I run locally needs the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` environment variable needs setting for my code to work. This is because I am connecting to an emulated Cosmos DB running locally on my machine which require Node to allow for self signed certificates.

I only want this environment variable setting when I run locally as in production I will be using a real (i.e. non emulated) Cosmos DB instance. Rather than putting and `#if debug` in my code (or the equivalent for a Node Azure Function) I'd like my VS Code project to set the env var when it is launched.

I've trying following [this answers advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/vs-code-run-command-at-launch-json) but when VS Code launches the program the environment variable is not set as I get a runtime error in my code about self signed certificates not being authorised. My `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: ",
    },
  ],
  "environment": [{
    "name": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED",
    "value": "0"
    }],
  }
```

If I set the env var directly in code using `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0` everything is fine. I don't know how I can get VS Code to set this, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update

`"environment": [{
    "name": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED",
    "value": "0"
    }],`

To Be

`"env": {
    "name": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED",
    "value": "0"
    },`

Also please check the alternatives.

You can Update package.json scripts to add all environment variables on start like `"runLocal": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ... your start code "`  or You can use third party lib called [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

this is how it works

01- Create .env file

02- Write all your environment variables key=val `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

03- Update package.json scripts to add `"runLocal": "NODE_ENV=dev ... your start code "`

04- Check if node `NODE_ENV` is equal `dev` then load the dotenv

05- Import module in case of node env is local and call config function `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out using dotenv. I found this article also useful: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786