# How can I automatically run my Vue project when I start the debugger in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, model-view-controller

I've got an MVC project in Visual Studio 2017, to which I've just added a Vue project (not from a Vue template), and I'm too lazy to open a command window and type `npm run serve` every time I start the debugger.  How can I automate this so I don't have to waste precious seconds?

Comment: Use a prelaunch task in your debugger config. It lets you basically pick a predefined 'task' that you've already made. You can make an `npm run serve` task in vscode from the tasks menu and then reference it as a prelaunch task in your debugger config. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/how-to-run-a-command-in-vs-code-with-launch-json)

Comment: @GBWDev I'm using Visual Studio 2017, not VSCode.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: you reminded me old days https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mithuns/2010/03/24/image-file-execution-options-ifeo/ you can do something like this. We used this for debugging startup of plugins that is being loaded by thirdparty