# How can I run multiple tasks on startup in VS Code each with different working directories?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have several projects in my workspace which I would like to start automatically in VS Code via task.

The structure is:

```
project1/folder1/folder2/ docker compose start
project1/folder1/folder3/ docker compose start 

project2/folder4/ docker start

project 3 ng serve
```

at best also
`ng lint` in Project 3.

In project 4 there are already launch tasks. These should also start automatically

I've already read up a bit on the topic and am trying my hand at the first tasks.json.

My problem at the moment is that I can not get into the subfolder and can not rundocker compose start. Also I don't know how to include the launch task.

The automatic start when opening VS Code works already once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make multiple individual tasks where you specify the and then use the [Compound Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) feature.

In each task, specify the current working directory using [the `options > cwd` field](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks). Using [the `${workspaceFolder}` variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) will probably be useful. Just for example (you might write your task with a different approach- Ex. using the "shell" type):

```json
"label": "Docker Folder 2",
"type": "process",
"command": "docker",
"args": ["compose", "start"],
"options": {
   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/project1/folder1/folder2/"
}
```

Then your compound task might look something like this (you can use the `runOptions > runOn` field to make the task run when the workspace folder opens):

```json
"label": "Docker",
"dependsOn": [
   "Docker: Project 1, Folder 2",
   "Docker: Project 1, Folder 3",
   "Docker: Project 2, Folder 4",
   "Docker: Project 3",
],
"runOptions": {
   "runOn": "folderOpen"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
That works. How can I add the task from the launch.json?

Comment: @Ludo google "`vscode run task from launch.json`" -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/43836861/11107541

Comment: No, I need it the other way around. I need an automatically starting task to start a run and debug session. 

With your suggestion I have to start the entry in the launch.json manually and then get a task executed automatically. But I want to automate the manual part.

Comment: ... I told you how to do exactly what you _wrote_ asking to do. So you asked wrong I suppose? If you want to run a task on startup, I already showed you how to do that. See the part of my answer that has "`runOn`".

Comment: RunOptions Arena not allowed in launch.json

Comment: @Ludo I have no idea what this "RunOptions Arena" is that you're talking about. can you refer me to something that explains it?

Comment: RunOptions are not allowed in launch.json. This is what i mean.

Comment: nowhere did I say to try putting runOptions in a launch.json. read what I linked you to. focus on the part that says `preLaunchTask`.

Comment: But that's the wrong direction.  So I have to start the launch task manually again.  I want it to be available as a task.  So he would restart the docker container when starting the launch task manually

Comment: @Ludo what exactly do you want to be available as a task and what as a launch config? I find your wording quite confusing.

Comment: I would like to start an entry in launch.json (whatever you call it now) via a task in Tasks.json.  This gives me the opportunity to do this when starting vscode.

Comment: @Ludo that's a different question. write a new question post. I'm pretty sure the answer is no.