How do I run my javafx app using fxml on VS code without project manager? I got Exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
This the 1st problem scenario:
When I run this program. which is a javafx UI using .fxml. it runs well when I run it using mvn exec: through maven project configuration. but doesn't run on default .json configuration (pressing f5). however, pressing f5 runs a simple javafx UI without .fxml.
I will post the codes and error for 1st condition below.
the project itself is sound. but here is the main class anyway:
public class MediaAppPlayer extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    try {
      System.out.println("im here ....................");
      // Load the FXMmnL file
      FXMLLoader loader =
          new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/MediaPlayer.fxml"));
      Parent root = loader.load();

      // Set up the scene
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

      // Bind the MediaView size to the scene size
      Controller controller = loader.getController();
      controller.bindMediaViewSize(scene);
      controller.bindHBoxSize(scene);

      // Set up the stage
      stage.setTitle("Media Player");
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();

      System.out.println("FXML file loaded sucessfully ....................");

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}

.json:
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}",
            //create java run time component
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/apps/javafx-sdk-21.0.5/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

        }
    ]
}

MediaPlayer.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="demo.Controller">
    <center>
        <VBox alignment = "CENTER">
            <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" />
            <Slider fx:id="seekSlider" min="0" max="100" />
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox fx:id="hBox" spacing="10">
            <Button text="Open File" onAction="#handleOpenFile" />
            <Button text="Play" onAction="#handlePlay" />
            <Button text="Pause" onAction="#handlePause" />
            <Button text="Stop" onAction="#handleStop" />
            <ImageView fitWidth="20" preserveRatio="true">
                <image>
                    <Image url="@icons/volumeicon.png" />
                </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Slider fx:id="volumeSlider" min="0" max="100" />
            <Label fx:id="currentTimeLabel" text="00:00" />
            <Label fx:id="totalTimeLabel" text="00:00" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>

Controller Class
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;
    @FXML
    private Slider volumeSlider;
    @FXML
    private Slider seekSlider;
    @FXML
    private Label currentTimeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label totalTimeLabel;
    @FXML
    private HBox hBox;

   
    

    private MediaManager mediaManager;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,10,0));
        mediaManager = new MediaManager(mediaView, volumeSlider, seekSlider, currentTimeLabel, totalTimeLabel);
    }
    public void bindMediaViewSize(Scene scene) {
        // Bind the MediaView size to the scene size
        mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(60)); // Adjust height to account for controls

        // Preserve the aspect ratio of the media
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    }

        // create a method to Bind the HBox and seeker slider size to the scene size
    public void bindHBoxSize(Scene scene) {
        // Bind the HBox and seeker slider size to the scene size
        hBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        seekSlider.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    } 
        

    @FXML
    private void handlePlay() {
        mediaManager.play();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handlePause() {
        mediaManager.pause();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleStop() {
        mediaManager.stop();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleOpenFile() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (file != null) {
            mediaManager.loadMedia(file);
        }
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin. here source and target has same java version to fix compatibility while build the project -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>21</source>
                <target>21</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Exec Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>demo.MediaAppPlayer</mainClass>
                
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>

Error
C:\Users\Kiran\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code\Media_Player\demo> cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:55228 
@C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_4l8owl80fisy30v5w8p9jmqto.argfile demo.MediaAppPlayer "
im here ....................
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)        
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x3a6815b) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x3a6815b
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2143)
        at demo.MediaAppPlayer.start(MediaAppPlayer.java:19)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.5/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application demo.MediaAppPlayer

note: that my project runs through maven pom command line instructions i.e mvn -exec:
but it never seems to run through the default .json configurations. with pressing f5. and I have managed to run javafx programs without fxml that way.
1st Scenerio: things I have done in this project, java fx runs without fxml:
-added dependencies using maven.
-checked java fx, jdk versions compatibility (they are good).
-added right vm args and main class in .json file
2nd Scenerio: without project framework and while creating a javafx program without fxml:
-I created lib,src,bin folders.
-added .jar files in lib.
-added right vm arguments pointing to that library.
-(optional) added classpaths in .json file. ( iam not sure how right it was)
Both of this condition doesn't work. idk what I am doing wrong. what I want to know is, how can I run a javafx project on VScode manually. which I tried and didn't work in the 2ndcondition. I can run it using a project manager. and in 1st condition, I used maven project manager to run a javafx program with .fxml file. it did work with mvn exec commands. but not with .json configuration. mind you, it runs if it is just javafx app without using .fxml file. what am i doing wrong here?

The image of your stack trace (note: do not upload images of code or errors), indicates you're getting a StackOverflowError.  It's odd though, because it seems like loading your FXML is repeatedly launching the application, yet the stack trace doesn't show any calls to Application::launch nor to anything related to your Controller class. Could you [edit] your question to show your FXML file and Controller class?

As for running your project from VS Code, see if https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx helps at all. Also see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_execute-maven-commands-and-goals and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/how-to-run-a-command-in-visual-studio-code-with-launch-json

Please, no lazy typing. Use proper case, punctuation, full sentences. This site is meant to be used by posterity, more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room.

@Slaw -> I did the changes you asked me to. also I don't think it is a stackOverflowError. what makes you say that?

"what makes you say that?" --  The fact that your image of the stack trace showed the same 9 methods being called over and over again without end. Also, that image didn't actually show the exception type, so I simply inferred the SOE. But the stack trace you added to the question as text is different and makes much more sense to me, at least conceptually.

That IllegalAccessError is fundamentally due to the same problem as in Module error when running JavaFx media application, but with javafx.fxml instead of javafx.media. The solution in your case would likely be to add javafx.fxml to your --add-modules argument. Except your launch.json seems to already do that, so I'm not sure why the FXML module is being loaded from the class-path instead of the module-path. What happens if you try one of the solutions where VS Code delegates to Maven (the last two links in my second comment).

@Slaw I did the same thing in another project and it worked, maybe it was just a fluke
